# gitlab-page for sphinx project is not working as expected

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, python-sphinx, gitlab-pages

The link to the whole project https://gitlab.com/ComplicatedPhenomenon/doubancrawler

I tested the generated document on local machine, it works fine
[image]

and gitlab page is as below (https://complicatedphenomenon.gitlab.io/doubancrawler/api.html)
[image]

Is there something wrong with `.gitlab-ci.yml`?

```yaml
image: python:3.7-alpine

test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - pip install -r requirements2.txt
  - cd docs/source/
  - sphinx-build -b html . public
  - mv public ../..
  only:
  - branches
  except:
  - master

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - pip install -r requirements2.txt
  - cd docs/source/
  - sphinx-build -b html . public
  - mv public ../..
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

Comment: This happens when autodoc can’t find/import your references. Maybe try installing your package first in the job or modifying `sys.path` in your sphinx config to make sure your modules can be imported when building docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when autodoc can’t find/import your references.

You are not installing all of the requirements for your project. In order for autodoc to work, you need to be able to import all your package modules. However, you’re only installing the requirements for building docs (requirements2.txt).

Otherwise, autodoc will receive an `ImportError` when trying to pull your doc strings because your modules attempt to import packages that are not installed.

Locally, you probably don’t have issues because you have already installed all of the requirements.

To fix this, add `pip install -r requirements.txt` to your job.

Comment: That's the case indeed, I should have carefully checked the generated log during GitLab CI/CD as there existed clues. Even the CI/CD passed at that time, lots of warnings remain.

Comment: Actually, it's not clear to me why autodoc need to check whether the import library is installed, to me, I think  the necessary work for autodoc is to check the grammar of the documentation.

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon because the autodoc extension does not use a static analysis technique. It uses `inspect`, which works by inspecting the Python objects, which requires the module be imported. Keep in mind, docstrings can be generated programmatically.

Comment: Now I'm less confused , I appreciate your explanation